# How can I org-download-clipboard in org-capture-templates?

Tags: org-capture

As org-protocol does not support images, I was thinking of calling org-download-clipboard from the org-capture-template.

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
         '
         ("l" "Protocol" entry (file "foo.org")
              "* TODO %:description \n%(org-download-clipboard)"
              :immediate-finish t
          )
         )
```

This would inline save the image on the clipboard to the org capture file, but it doesn't work;)

Any pointers as to what I can try?

Comment: `org-download-clipboard` depends on the operating system. Which operating system are you working on?

Comment: Xorg on NixOS (x86_64)